# What will be the frequency count of this code snippet?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, data-structures

```
int i=0,j;

while(i<=n)
{
 while(j<=(i+1)){ 
   a=a*a;
    j++;
  }
i++;
```

This question was in my homework and we have to calculate the frequency count of the code above. I am having difficulty understanding how the code will execute and how many times will the loops execute. I know the inner loop is dependent on 'i', otherwise I'm lost.

Comment: Do you reset $j$ before the second while loop? If not, then the second loop will take only one operation, since $j$ would already be incremented a big nch of times

Comment: Is this typed exactly as its written, or are there possibly some errors in typing it?

Comment: This how to question was given to me in my homework. I made no changes

Comment: $j$ is initialized to what? Without it, no claim can be made. Your homework question is incorrect in that case.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)/[How do I ask a Good Homework Question?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1286) `I am having difficulty understanding how the code will execute and how many times will the loops execute.` Starting with unbalanced braces? If completed&interpreted as a snippet in a "C-like" programming language, it "invokes undefined behaviour" for lack of initialisation of `j`, if not `a`. Without anything being used, an "optimising compiler" would conceivably "optimise everything away", emit no code.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> Statement         Frequency Count
> int i=0,j                1
> while(j<=(i+1))         n+1
>  a=a*a                   n
>  j++                     n
> i++                      1
> ```

f(n) = 3n+3 = Time Complexity
Degree is O(n)

Space:
a = n
i = 1
j = 1
S(n) = n+1 = Space Complexity
Degree is O(n)

Comment: `Space [needed for] a = n` please elaborate on this.